# Making IMG in an LI fill the screen

Tags: html, css

I am displaying some images in an unordered list (as the full code is a actually  slideshow) and have managed to get mysef utterly confused.

When I hard-code the image size to 1920x1080 everything displays as expected on my 1920x1080 monitor, however, I don't want to hardcode the size in case the screen size changes for some reason.

I just can't figure out how to make the images (and the li they are in) fill the screen.

The page is being displayed in Chrome/Chromium in full-screen mode.

My code is currently as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SlideShow</title>

<style>

  body {
    background: #000;
    overfow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
  }
  
  ul, img {
   width: auto;
   height: 1080px;
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
  }
   
  ul, li, img {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: auto auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: none !important;
  }
  
  .slideshow {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0em auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
  }

  .slideshow > li {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

</style>

</head>
<body>
<ul id="stage" class="slideshow">
  <li title="1920x1080 Raster Test"><img src="1920x1080raster.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt=""></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The images that are being displayed are all 1920x1080px in size, so it is just the filling of the filling of the screen without borders or cropping if a larger or smaller display is used that is my current problem (I'm ignorin aspect ratio as I've resized al limages for this purpose).

I managed to get the image to stretch to fill horizonally at one point, but it remained just 1080px high, and I now can'tremember what I changed to achieve that either!

Comment: Apply overflow: hidden; to the body element in CSS to prevent content from overflowing outside the viewport.



Use width: 100vw; and height: 100vh; for the ul and li selectors to make them fill the entire viewport width and height, respectively.



Add object-fit: cover; to the ul li img selector to ensure images fill their li containers without distortion, scaling and cropping as needed.



Remove any hardcoded width and height attributes from the img tags in the HTML to allow images to adapt dynamically to their parent container.

Comment: @Gauravsinghrajpoot thanks! That got me on the right track. 100vw and 100vh were the bits I'd forgotten, and object-fit is completely new to me but very very useful! Though I actually needed `object-fit: contain;` rather than `cover` to get the required result. (Do you want to add this as an answer so that I can accept?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `overflow: hidden;` to the `body` element in CSS to prevent content from overflowing outside the viewport.

Use `width: 100vw;` and `height: 100vh;` for the `ul` and `li` selectors to make them fill the entire viewport width and height, respectively.

Add `object-fit: cover;` or `object-fit: contain;` to the `ul li img` selector to ensure images fill their `li` containers without distortion, scaling and cropping as needed.

Remove any hardcoded `width` and `height` attributes from the `img` tags in the HTML to allow images to adapt dynamically to their parent container.

Comment: I actually needed `object-fit: contain;` rather than `cover` to get the required result, but marking this as correct as it led me to the right answer.